# No ProjectInfo.xml files were found

Tags: visual-studio, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

i am using `visual studio 2015` and `tfs` for build the project,
I started the build but got stuck with the error described below,

```
2016-03-17T09:38:15.2135195Z ##[error]No ProjectInfo.xml files were found. Possible causes:
2016-03-17T09:38:15.2135195Z ##[error]1. The project has not been built - the end step was called right after the begin step, without a build step in between
2016-03-17T09:38:15.2135195Z ##[error]2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 12.0 upwards are supported
2016-03-17T09:38:15.2135195Z ##[error]3. The build step has been launched from a different working folder
2016-03-17T09:38:15.2135195Z Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete SonarQube analysis.
2016-03-17T09:38:15.2135195Z 15:08:15.15  Creating a summary markdown file...
2016-03-17T09:38:15.2135195Z ##[error]Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
2016-03-17T09:38:15.2135195Z ##[error]Unexpected exit code received from batch file: 1
```

Can any one help me in this?

Comment: Share your build steps here, and let us know what do you want to achieve.

Comment: What's the MSBuild version installed on build server?

Comment: i am using visual studio 2015, and team foundation server 2015 which is attach to the visual studio,,,,,i have a generated a project solution of .net project and trying to create a build and sonarqube code analysis,
For this i am using tfs 2015 and these are the build steps i am following  1)sonarqube for MSbuild begin anaysis 2) visual studio build, 3) visual studio test 4) sonarqube for MSbuild begin anaysis 5) index sources and public symbols 6) publish buid artifact.....all stages builds is passed but i am getting error at "Finish the analysis and upload the results to SonarQube"..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using TFS2015 vNext build, and you are trying to add build tasks below to execute a SonarQube analysis:

· SonarQube for MSBuild – Begin Analysis

· SonarQube for MSBuild – End Analysis

From your error log, you need to make sure the End Analysis task should be used to create a step that is executed after the “**Visual Studio Build**” task step. Review blog [Build Tasks for SonarQube Analysis](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/08/24/build-tasks-for-sonarqube-analysis/) get more information of how to use SonarQube analysis tasks.

Comment: hello cece,  i have done the things as you said, and i got new error ,,, i have described it below in details

Comment: The error message point out "Caused by: com.A.vb.XYZ.A.A.A: Missing or bad plugin license." I guess the plugin you want to use is a commercial product, so you need to buy a license if you want to use it. Check this website for more information of plugin: http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/